# Where do I get a Geolocation History dataset

Tags: data-request

I would like to do a mobility research over a well defined geographical area. In an ideal world, I would need a dataset containing anonymized geo-location information from date X to date Y of the users that moved across that region.

I was wondering if Google sells those data? After all, they collect it through the Google Location History, which (as far as I know) is also used to get real-time traffic data on Google Maps...

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/openmobiledata_public?pli=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[History of Locations of an android mobile in the month of October 2014](https://www.kaggle.com/juliansimon/location-history)

The history of locations of each of the mobile can be downloaded from this link:
[Source](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout/custom/location_history)

These data are interesting to perform geolocation studies associated with time.

Format file: JSON

---

If you are willing to buy the data, you can find the below link

[Datarade](https://datarade.ai/data-categories/location-data)

Location data is information relating to the geographic coordinates of a person or object. It's mostly used by retailers and marketers e.g. in-store location optimization and location-based advertising. Datarade helps you find the right location data providers and datasets.